# Strange exceptions using FluentNHibernate automapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, s#arp-architecture, automapping

I have the following entities in my domain model. A group (an aggregate root) contains items (which are aggregate roots themselves) but an item can only be contained by one group at the time. The code below enforces this. The reason for the group to have an Items collection is that in the domain there are certain cases that are most logically solved by providing access items by means of a group.

When I add an item to my group however, I get this `FatalExecutionEngineError`:

> The runtime has encountered a fatal
>   error. The address of the error was at
>   0x5f0b8442, on thread 0x99c. The error
>   code is 0xc0000005. This error may be
>   a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or
>   non-verifiable portions of user code.
>   Common sources of this bug include
>   user marshaling errors for COM-interop
>   or PInvoke, which may corrupt the
>   stack.

Right after that, a `System.ExecutionEngineException` is thrown with no inner exception.

**UPDATE**

It seems that the `_items.Contains(item)` check in the `Item.AssignTo` method causes this exception to be thrown. I initially left this check out of the example but I have now added it. When I remove the check, I get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` at the `_items.Add(item);` statement.

This is my (simplified) domain model:

```
public class Group : Entity
{
    private List<Item> _items = new List<Item>();

    public virtual IEnumerable<Item> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
    }

    public virtual void Assign(Item item)
    {
        if (_items.Contains(item))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Already assigned.", "item");
        }

        _items.Add(item);
    }
}

public class Item : Entity
{
    public virtual Group Group
    {
        get;
        protected set;
    }

    public virtual void AssignTo(Group group)
    {
        group.Assign(this);
        this.Group = group;
    }
}
```

The FluentNHibernate mapping overrides:

```
// AutoMapping<Group> 
mapping
    .HasMany(n => n.Documents)
    .Access.ReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
    .Cascade.Delete()
    .Inverse();
```

So, the exception is thrown when I call `Item.AssignTo`. When I remove the `group.Assign(this);` line from `Item.AssignTo` the exception is not raised. But ofcourse, in that case `Document.Items` stays empty until the document is retrieved from a repository sometime later.

What am I doing wrong or missing here?

Comment: can you create a standalone testcase? FatalExecutionEngineErrors are usually CLR bugs, just as the description says. Make sure you have all fixes applied. What framework version are you using?

Comment: Can you step into Item.AssignTo with a debugger?

Comment: @Mauricio: I will try to make a standalone testcase as soon as possible, good idea. I'm using .NET Framework 4.0 by the way. S#arpArch is at v1.9 and NHibernate v3.

Comment: @Jason: jeez, how could I even forget to do that. Thanks! The exception is thrown at `_items.Contains(item)`. I had initially left that statement out. By the way, if I remove that check, I get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` at `_items.Add(item);`.

Comment: Does it work if you replace `IEnumerable<Item>` with `IList<Item>` ?

Comment: @k3b: thanks but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: why are you specifying it as a read only property? If you can add items to it?

Comment: Items is a read only property because this way, I can control what goes in. In reality, I might want to perform more checks, like restricting the number of items etc. This approach is part of Domain Driven Design.

Comment: Are you overriding the Hashcode or Equals methods?  If there was an error in those the Contains method might throw an exception

Comment: @Jason: I'm not overriding those but S#arpArchitecture is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boy, I wonder what's really going on here. I created a standalone testcase to reproduce the problem but somehow it ran just fine. While I was experimenting some more with the full project, I found that changing `private List<Item> _items = new List<Item>();` to `private IList<Item> _items = new List<Item>();`, solved the problem!

All of this makes me suspect there is bug in NHibernate somewhere but most of my former bug suspicions regarding external libraries turned out being bugs in my own code so I'm being a bit careful making such accusations.